# PHP / SQL out of memory: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1310720) (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes)

Tags: php, sql, memory, memory-management

I'm running the following query, with two longtext fields (175 & 525), and I get the error out of memory. Is this query already too long or is something else happening?

Error: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1310720) (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes)

```
$query = "SELECT username, url, accountcreated, accountstatus, address, city, birthday, education, relation, gender, profile_story, intsettinga, intsettingb FROM users WHERE username=?";

$stmt = $db->stmt_init();
($stmt->prepare($query))|| fail('An error occurred: MySQL prepare', $db->error);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$username)|| fail('An error occurred: MySQL bind_param', $db->error);
$stmt->execute()|| fail('An error occurred: MySQL execute', $db->error);
$stmt->bind_result($screenname, $url, $created, $status, $address, $city, $bday, $education, $relation, $gender, $profile, $settinga, $ssettingb)|| fail('An error occurred: MySQL bind_result', $db->error);
$stmt->fetch() || fail('Profile not found');
$stmt->close();
$db->close();
```

Comment: How many records do you have in the table?

Comment: only 3 records for now

Comment: It is kind of strange that I would need 4gb of memory, or is that not what tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes means in this message

Comment: I found the answer, the bind_result took too much memory, $stmt->store_result(); solved it, call it before bind_result

Comment: Something is not quite right here at all - a query on 3 records shouldn't use up that much memory, and `store_result` would only make it worse - because `store_result` would fetch all the results and keep them in PHP's memory, thus using even more of it.

Comment: I'll have to look into that, weird thing is, it's only a few lines of code. Just some small strings and integer's. No clue qhere 4gb comes from. I'm passing 3 queries in a row though on different tables, but the db is more or less empty and only one table really has columns (app. 15). Any clue where I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

The error was at bind_result, adding $stmt->store_result(); solved it:

```
$stmt->execute()|| fail('An error occurred: MySQL execute', $db->error);

$stmt->store_result(); 

$stmt->bind_result($screenname, $url, $created, $status, $address, $city, $bday, $education, $relation, $gender, $profile, $settinga, $ssettingb)|| fail('An error occurred: MySQL bind_result', $db->error);
$stmt->fetch() || fail('Profile not found');
$stmt->close();
$db->close();
```